# 4-Color Stacking Game Winning Strategy

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

This game is played with rocks of 4 colors.

Initially, there are N 1-rock stacks on the ground (N>5). Each stack has a size (number of its rocks) and a color (color of the rock on top of that stack) there is at least one rock of each color in the beginning. At each turn, the player whose turn it is can move a stack of rocks on top of another stack, given the two stacks have either the same size or the same color. so the two stacks $S_1$ and $S_2$ turn into one stack with size [size($S_1$)+size($S_2$)] and the color of whichever stack that was moved on top of the other.
The game ends when there is no other move possible and the person who played the last move wins.

edit based on comments: So what's obvious here is that in the final state of the game we will have 1, 2, 3, or 4 stacks remaining (depending on how many colors are left) and creating each stack of size $K$ takes a total of $K-1$ moves throughout the game. So, assuming there are $t$ stacks left in the final state if $N-t$ is odd, the first player wins, and otherwise, the second player wins.

I am looking for a way to find a winning strategy (if there is one)

Comment: Nice game! However I don't understand your analysis of the 'small' cases in the end. If there is one stack, no move can be made and the first player to move *loses* rather than wins, right? Also with three stacks of sizes 1, 2, 3 and different colors no moves can be made, while with three stacks of sizes 1, 2, 3 and colors red, blue, red one move can be made and no move afterwards so with 3 stacks it seems that who wins depends on the precise sizes and colors. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Vincent I think I was a little vague in my last paragraph. First of all, right now I am solving the problem for exactly 4 colors. Now, what I meant was not for small cases. It refers to the ending state of the game. In the end there are 1, 2, 3, or 4 stacks left (at least one stack and at most one of each color with different sizes for each). Creating each stack of size n takes n-1 moves throughout the game so sum of number of moves throughout the game is a number between N-1 and N-4 given how many stacks are left in the end. this determines the winner (N-1, N-3 first player wins else second)

Comment: @AlalehAhmadian Isn't that the case only if $N$ is even otherwise first player wins for $N-2,N-4$?

Comment: What I came up with is that if there is 1, 3 stacks left in the end the first player wins (regardless of N) and otherwise second

Comment: @AlalehAhmadian - I _think_ you're saying that if the game starts with $N>5 $ stacks, guaranteed to have at least one of each color, and the game ends with $m$ stacks (obviously all different colors), then it is a first person win if $m=1,3$.  But this cannot be true.  There have been exactly $N-m$ turns to reduce $N$ stacks to $m$ stacks, and it is first player win iff $N-m$ is odd.  It depends on both the parity of $N$ and parity of $m$.

Comment: @antkam Yes, I think you guys are right